# How to mock a not implemented method with Rhino Mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino

I have this simplified implementation and the unit test below:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int GetSomeValue()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public Parent MyParent { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent GetParent()
    {
        return MyParent;
    }

    public virtual int GetParentsValue()
    {
        var parent = GetParent();

        return parent.GetSomeValue();
    }
}
```

How can I test the GetParentsValue() method with Rhino Mock without implement the parent's GetSomeValue() method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Child target = new Child();

Parent mockParent = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Parent>();
mockParent.Stub(x => x.GetSomeValue()).Return(1);

target.MyParent = mockParent;

int value = target.GetParentsValue();

Assert.AreEqual(value, 1);
```

Comment: I was failed on intitializing mockParent. I didn't use the Stub.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
Child child = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<Child>();
child.Stub(c => c.GetParentsValue()).Return(1);

Assert.AreEqual(1, child.GetParentsValue());
```

If you want to test some internals of the GetParentsValue() method you should mock `Parent.GetSomeValue()` with:

```
Parent mockParent = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Parent>();
mockParent.Stub(x => x.GetSomeValue()).Return(1);

target.MyParent = mockParent;
```